# Submitted humanities PhD applications (US) but concerned with potentially wrong documents submitted

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, errors-erratum

I recently applied to a few PhD programs in the US. Perhaps because of my drowsiness due to working late, I wasn't paying full attention when I was checking my documents (statements of purpose, personal history statements, writing samples) for the last time prior to final submission. I only thought of the possibility that I might have accidentally swapped some documents after submitting my applications.

The reason why I am even concerned at all is: I didn't name my documents with the schools I'm applying to; I only placed them into folders named after the schools. There is program/department but not school information on the heading of each of my documents, so if I had submitted something wrong, people might be able to notice through the heading. I have tried to email/call two schools' admissions, but I have not received any helpful responses or, in one case, any response at all. The schools that I'm trying to contact don't provide application proofs through their online portals; in other words, I can't directly check what I have submitted.

My question is, would committees contact you if they notice there might have been a swapping mistake in your applications? If not likely, should I keep on contacting the admissions despite having received no response?

Thank you for your time and interest!

Comment: Is it possible you're overthinking this?

Comment: It is very possible... But at the same time, I have been prone to making such mistakes even with my best intention, so I have to wonder...